# Mouse position and a QDialog

Tags: qt, qdialog

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to make a qdialog to input the co-ordinates of a line such that the co-ordinates can be given by mouse position or a qdialog (via QLineEdit items). Is there a way to have the mouse position be displayed in the QLinedEdit items in the qdialog when moving the mouse of the canvas or move the line points when typing in the dialog?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried yourself?

Comment: I have not tried any decent code because I have no clue if this can be done. I ma thinking to use signals to write in the QLineEdit, but so far i found only QLineEdit.setText() ... but it generate segmentation fault.

Comment: It can be done. Check the class [QMouseEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#details) which can return `QPoint`or `QPointF` as mouse is moving. Transform them to what you want and display it on `QLineEdit`

Comment: I think the solution is in using signals form a mousemoveevent to the qlineedit, but in order to work i need to use QLineEdit.setText() which for some reason generate segmentation faults when i use it and breaks the code.

Comment: Why it generats segmentation faults? Could you update the post and show us what you have tried?

Comment: IT is described above. It generate segmentation faults because the old code was accessing a QVector or pointers before this one was filled.